# Retorno Trigger Java

Tags: java, trigger

Possuo uma trigger que verifica se o login do usuario possui mais de 3 caracteres e se nao tiver ele retorna a msg "o login deve possuir mais de 3 caracteres", como posso capturar esse retorno no java e mostrar em um Joptionpane?
com o `try catch(Exception e)` ele só mostra o java.lang.Exception...

```
try {
                occurrence.insert(ocorrencia, usuarioLogado);                
            } catch (Exception e) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());

            }
```

Grato

Comment: Se trocar o `e.getMessage()` por `e.getErrorCode()` chega aparecer a mensagem personalizada do banco?

Comment: Não aparece esse método para utilizar..

Comment: No catch troque a `Exception` por `SQLException` veja se aparece.

Comment: Resolvi com e.getcause().getmessage().toString;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema usando o

```
e.getCause().getMessage().toString();
```